# Multi-column IN/ANY postgres query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, go

Sample table schema:

```
create table t1(
  col1 varchar(20),
  col2 varchar(20)
);
```

Requirement:
Fetch rows that match any of the tuples (col1, col2) presented in an array.

SQL:

```
select * from t1 where (col1, col2) in (('c11', 'c12'), ('c21', 'c22'));
```

I want to write this query in Go using the "database/sql" package with "github.com/lib/pq" driver, and that is where I am facing the problem.

I can easily do this for single column IN/ANY query.

for example, the following query

```
select * from t1 where col1 in ('c11', 'c21');
```

can be achieved with the following code snippet:

```
args := []string{"c11", "c21}
conn.Exec(`select * from t1 where col1 = any($1)`, pq.Array(args))
```

However, I could not use similar approach for multi-column query.
I tried passing `pq.Array([][]string)`, `pq.Array([]*pq.StringArray)` etc. as argument, but they do not work, and fetches the following error:

```
input of anonymous composite types is not implemented
```

Will appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```golang
args := [][]string{{"c11","c21"},{"c21","c22"}}
params := make([]interface{}, len(args)*2)
tuples := make([]string, len(args))
for i := range args {
    params[i*2] = args[i][0]
    params[i*2+1] = args[i][1]
    tuples[i] = fmt.Sprintf("($%d,$%d)", i*2+1,i*2+2)
}
invals := "(" + strings.Join(tuples, ",")) + ")"
conn.Exec("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (col1,col2) IN " + invals, params...)
```

---

For a two-column tuple you should be able to do the following:

```golang
conn.Exec(`SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE (col1,col2) IN (
    SELECT * FROM json_each_text(json_object($1::text[]))
)`, pq.Array([][]string{{"c11","c21"},{"c21","c22"}}))
```

Comment: Yes, ended up doing that kind of implementation. I was actually looking for a more implicit way of doing this, but I guess that does not exist.

Comment: @ChayanGhosh I've updated the answer with an alternative approach that may be more to your liking.

Comment: That's awesome @mkopriva, yes that's the kind of solution I was looking for. json_each_text proved to be a charm in this. Thanks a lot.